# After getting value from javascript redirect to another page in codeigniter with url parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I am making a simple auto search, where when user after searching, the search results get displayed on the dropdown box. If he clicks to any of the search items, it will take the user to another page where more details will be shown regarding that item.

So as, if he clicks on "Discrete Maths", then the new page url will be

```
localhost/example/search?s=discrete+maths
```

and the details will be shown regarding that topic

My javascript code :

```
function searchclick(subid,subjct){ 
          //subid is subject id and subjct is subject name   

             var search_var = {

              action : "gosearch",
              subid : subid,
              subjct : subjct
                              };

              $.ajax({

               type : "POST",
               url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>search",
               cache : false,
               data : search_var,
               success : function(r)
               {


               }
             });
}
```

I have a controller called Search which loads the view known as search.

I want to pass those data to that controller which will then redirect to the Search view with the url like this --> `localhost/example/search?s=discrete+maths` as well as the title of the page will change to the name of the item searched.

I can't figure out a way. I'm new to codeigniter.

I just want to redirect to that view after getting the data and change the url parameters. Nothing else. Only this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After sending data to controller in controller do whatever you need to do and redirect directly to desired URL:

```
public function search() {
  /* your code */
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
}
```

If you need to send back some data to front end you can send new URL to JS on front end and redirect there:

```
// controller
public function search() {
  /* your code */
  $arr = array('redirect' => 'http://example.com/', 'other_data' => 1);    
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode( $arr );
}

// javascript
  success : function(response){ 
             window.location.replace(response['redirect'])
            },
```

This is not codeigniter specific information. This is general AJAX method.

Comment: how can i change the url adding parameters?

Comment: URL is just a string sou you can simply do

$url = "http://www.example.com/" . "?search?s=" . $parameter;
header("Location: $url");

You have some serious lack o basic knowledge about PHP. Please do some tutorial.